# Angular4 Observable Subscription to ServiceStack Server Events

Tags: angular, servicestack, rxjs, angular2-observables

We have an Angular 1 app that polls a ServiceStack web API every few seconds and as part of the upgrade to Angular 4 I'd like to swap this out for a rxjs observable subscription to ServiceStack's Server Events.

Does anyone know if this is possible or should I just be using ss-utils for my subscription?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Angular4 it's recommended to use [TypeScript Server Events Client](http://docs.servicestack.net/typescript-server-events-client) in the 
[servicestack-client npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/servicestack-client) which provides access to all of ServiceStack high-level Server Events API.

You could potentially create observables for each of the events you're interested in, e.g:

```
var onMessage, onException, onJoin, CustomMessage;

let onMessage$ = Observable.create((observer) => {
   onMessage = (msg:ServerEventMessage) => {
      this.zone.run(() => observer.next(msg));
   };
   onException = (e:Error) => observer.error(error);
}

let onJoin$ = Observable.create((observer) => {
   onJoin = (msg:ServerEventJoin) => {
      this.zone.run(() => observer.next(msg));
   };
}

let customMessage$ = Observable.create((observer) => {
   CustomMessage = (msg:CustomMessage) => {
      this.zone.run(() => observer.next(msg));
   };
}

const client = new ServerEventsClient("/", channels, {
    handlers: {
        onConnect: (sub:ServerEventConnect) => {  // Successful SSE connection
            console.log("You've connected! welcome " + sub.displayName);
        },
        onJoin,
        onMessage,
        CustomMessage
    },
    onException
 })
.start();
```

But I'm not familiar enough with RxJS to know if this is the best way to use RxJS.

Answer (score 2):

```
let serverEvent$ = Observable.create(
                    (observer) => {
                      let eventSource = this.sseService.createEventSource('http://localhost:8080/servereventapi');
                      eventSource.onmessage = (event) => {
                          this.zone.run(() => observer.next(JSON.parse(event.data)));
                      };
                      eventSource.onerror = (error) => observer.error(error);
                  });

//subscribe to the event
```

Comment: hello, can you give a complete example please